# Django ModelChoiceField initial value not working despite it is well set up

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have the following form :

```
class UserUpdateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields= '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'inscription_date': forms.DateInput(format=('%d-%m-%Y'),
                                                 attrs={'class': 'datepicker',
                                                        'placeholder': 'Select a date'})
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_user_id = User.objects.get(id=self.instance.id).id
        group_name = GroupName.objects.filter(
            usergroup__user__id=current_user_id).get().name
        current_location = User.objects.filter(id=self.instance.id).values(
            location=F('record__location__nom')).distinct().get()

        self.fields['location'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Location.objects.all(), initial=current_location['location'])



    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        return form
```

The initial value is not working. I checked and the value inside `current_location['location']`is correct.

I tried as well to write `self.initial['location'] = current_location['location']` but still not working.

This is the way, I instantiate my form :

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class UserUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserUpdateForm
    template_name = 'dashboard/users/user_update_form.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, "The user %s was updated successfully" % (
            self.object.first_name))
        return reverse_lazy('dashboard:users')
```

Do you have any clues ?

Comment: The fields should be `__all__`, not `__all`

Comment: Sorry don't in account that. It is not the case in my code because I have edited manually in stack. So the fields are working properly